# Which pool to choose from Java Util concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a bunch of tasks:

```
public class ProcessDay implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        List<ProcessHour> hr = //required hours
        //do some post actions
    }
}

public class ProcessHour implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        List<ProcessMinutes> mins = //required minutes
        //do some post actions
    }
}
```

`ProcessSeconds`, `ProcessMonth`, ... etc
And so forth. It would be convinient to use `ForkJoinPool` here but it's not good from performance standpoint, because `ProcessXXX` tasks are being submitted to a cluster of machines and hence the method invocation itself is very short.

So for performance it's good to use `Executors.cachedThreadPoolExecutor`. But is there a way to combine ForkJoinPool with chachedThreadPool semantic. I mean creating threads on demand and release them if not used.

Maybe there is a better approach to this? Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

> I mean creating threads on demand and release them if not used.

That is how cached thread pool operates. It starts with 0 threads and creates a new one each time when there is a new task to process and all threads in the pool are busy. Thread is terminated if it was idle for 60 seconds.
Default cached thread pool is created using the following `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor:

```
return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0,
                              Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                              60L,
                              TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                              new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>())
```

It created with 0 possible idle threads in pool, unlimited maximum number of threads, 60 seconds timeout before idle thread is terminated, and queue implementation that doesn't store tasks and just transfers them between pool and its threads. Such pool is suitable for lots of short-lived tasks that is probably your case. As you can see it's also pretty easy to adjust it configuration according to your needs using direct `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor.